# Kendo UI Angular grid - Button color not appearing

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to make demo in "KendoUI Grid" using angular. I have used "Kendo-Bootstrap" theme. Everything works properly instead of button color of command cells like `kendoGridEditCommand` and `kendoGridSaveCommand`.

**code:**

```html
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
          <kendo-grid-column></kendo-grid-column>
          <kendo-grid-column></kendo-grid-column>
...
            <kendo-grid-column title="Action">
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-isNew="isNew">
                    <button kendoGridEditCommand class="k-primary k-button">Edit</button>
                    <button kendoGridRemoveCommand class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    <button kendoGridSaveCommand [disabled]="formGroup?.invalid">{{ isNew ? 'Add' : 'Update' }}</button>
                    <button kendoGridCancelCommand>Cancel</button>
                </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
            
</kendo-grid>
```

When i try to remove `kendoGridEditCommand` it renders the color of button properly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!